# где хранить file_id чтобы при перезапуске кода все новые сохраненные в списках file_id не стирались

Tags: python, telebot

Суть кода заключается в том что я отправляю боту документ, фото, видео, он считывает айди файла и заносит в список. но если бот перезапускается все накопленные айди слетают и надо делать всё заново. куда и как сохранять эти file_id чтобы они прям в код записывались а не в оперативной памяти хранились?

вот пример подгрузки file_id в список:

`

```
if text == 'f_id1':        
    bot.send_message(chat_id, '<b>Жду фото</b>', parse_mode='html')
        while text != 'стоп':
            @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
            def get_use_doc(message1):
                photo = message1
                f_id1.append(photo.photo.file_id)
                bot.send_message(chat_id, '<b>Принял фото</b>', parse_mode='html')
        bot.send_message(chat_id, '<b>Загрузили</b>')`
```

Comment: Ну, в файл, например?

Comment: Не надо в код. Запишите ваш список в `json` файл, а при старте бота читайте этот список обратно. Ну или можно в БД.